# edit control and delete button overlap separator line in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I wanna keep separator line in edit mode of UITableView but don't know how to.

When edit control and edit button active, their frames are overlap the separator line like this:
[image]

I change background color for odd and even cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noteCon"];


    return cell;
}
```

And change background color for edit control and delete button in custom cell

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) {
        [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setBackgroundColor:self.contentView.backgroundColor];
    }
    if (state == 3) {
        [[self.subviews objectAtIndex:3] setBackgroundColor:self.contentView.backgroundColor];
    }
}
```

How to display separator line when tableView in edit mode? Thanks!

Comment: can you give example of any app where its already been implemented?

Comment: This is my [sample code](https://github.com/lequysang/gitfiles02/blob/master/MyTableView.zip). You can see a blue line in bottom of cell is cut of